# Ending joint-tenancy agreement by sending registered mail to the landlord - was it done properly?

Tags: united-kingdom, rental-property, landlord, rent, tenant

6th September sent the Special Delivery to the landlord:

[image]

[image]

[image]

*(courtesy of me - sent an email informing letting agent about the situation)*

#### Snippets from tenancy agreement

> Commencing on: 7 September 2016
>
> Term of Rental: Twelve Months
>
> 1.2 The obligations and liabilities of the Parties under this Agreement are Joint and Several.
>
> 1.3 The Parties listed above agree that the Landlord’s Agent may provide their name, address
>   and other contact details to third parties including, but not limited to, the Landlord,
>   contractors, referencing companies, utility providers, the local authority and the appropriate
>   tenancy deposit protection scheme provider. The obligations and liabilities of the Parties
>   under this Agreement are Joint and Several.
>
> Notices under Section 47 & 48 of the Landlord and Tenant Act 1987:
>   For the purpose of Section 47 & 48 of the Landlord and Tenant Act 1987 the address at
>   which any Notices (including Notices in any proceedings) may be served on the Landlord by
>   the Tenant, is as set out below, until the Tenant is notified in writing to the contrary.
>
> 13 Upon the expiry of this fixed term of Rental, if no instruction has been received by either
>   the Landlord or the Tenant, then the Agreement shall become statutory periodic. This
>   means that the agreement will continue on a monthly basis until notice is received, two
>   months from the Landlord and one month from the Tenant.

#### Research I did back then

I did a lot of research how to remove myself from the tenancy.
I did call Shelter - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shelter_(charity) - I did follow their recommendation. The rationale was as follows:

- There is joint tenancy
- It automatically continues...
- ...unless it is cancelled
- Therefore I did cancel

I genuinely thought that charity dealing with homelessness is the best source of information.

---

#### Was cancellation to renew done properly?

Now I'm being told that the landlord didn't agree.

Does the landlord have to agree?

Answer (score 3):

### No, it was not done properly

See [here](http://researchbriefings.files.parliament.uk/documents/SN05149/SN05149.pdf).

You **cannot**, and the landlord **cannot** agree to remove your name from the joint tenancy.

You **can** cancel the tenancy for both of you, as can your ex. If you do this, the landlord is not under any obligation to offer your ex a lease on the same terms or at all so they would risk becoming homeless.

The court has the power under the Family Law Act to make such a substitution so you can apply to them for such an order.

Comment: "It is open to any of the joint tenants to serve a valid notice to terminate
the tenancy but before doing so they should seek professional legal
advice on the implications." - HMMM - I'm worried I've messed up again relying on volunteer knowledge rather than spending £££ for lawyers... I still don't quite understand where?